# SQL Query to count entries in the column and get percentage

Tags: sql, influxdb, influxql

| student | have new books |
| --- | --- |
| alice | yes |
| bob | yes |
| candace | no |
| dalia | no |
| edd | no |
| frank | yes |

expected output 50

essentially i want to count the total number of rows and and students that have new books and get the percentage of students with new books

Comment: Add sample input for your expected output.

Comment: was editing, not too familiar using this platform

Answer (score 0):

Use the conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select count(case when have_new_book = 'yes' then 1 end) / count(*)
 from your_Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Three methods shown:

```
create table t(student,have_new_books);
insert into t values
  ('alice',     'yes'),
  ('bob',       'yes'),
  ('candace',   'no'),
  ('dalia',     'no'),
  ('edd',       'no'),
  ('frank',     'yes');

select sum(case have_new_books when 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)*100 / count(*) yes_percent
  from t;

select have_new_books,count(*)*100/(select count(*) from t) percent
  from t
  group by have_new_books;

select sum(have_new_books='yes')*100/count(*) yes_percent
  from t;
```

Tested with SQLite3 but they should work on most other engines (3rd possibly only on SQLite3).

Output:

```
┌─────────────┐
│ yes_percent │
├─────────────┤
│ 50          │
└─────────────┘
┌────────────────┬─────────┐
│ have_new_books │ percent │
├────────────────┼─────────┤
│ no             │ 50      │
│ yes            │ 50      │
└────────────────┴─────────┘
┌─────────────┐
│ yes_percent │
├─────────────┤
│ 50          │
└─────────────┘
```